# Need to create a ksh script for transferring files between application server and db server

Tags: linux, ksh

I have a requirement where I need to automate the transfer of a particular file from one location in the application server to the database server.

I can do it manually by using these steps but I need it in the script

```
#! /bin/ksh

directory path where the file need to be

ftp (hostname of the application server)

 username

 password

file location in the apps server

get filename

quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using the following:

```
ftp -inv <<EOF
open app.server.address
user username password
cd some/location
get filename
bye
EOF
```

The `ftp` `-i` option turns off interactive prompting and `-n` disables auto-login along with the username and password prompts.

Comment: @sam The `<<` was interpreted as an opening html tag, causing the main part of your post to be hidden. I think this is what caused Anthon to believe your post was merely a "thank you". Fixed it for you, but in the future you can avoid it by indenting code blocks by four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Several FTP clients allow you to specify username a password on the command line, two that I know of are `ncftp` and `lftp`. You can then use a single command, non-interactive, to retrieve the file inside the script.

Comment: Thanks john for you response , I really appreciate for your time..... I tried using this in a script but it is asking me to enter username and password.... how can i automate and can execute the script without the promt of username and password

Comment: Don't use the standard ftp client. As I said, use `lftp` or `ncftp` or another client that lets you pass the username and password on the command line. When you do so, you don't get prompted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid storing the username and password in the script itself you can create an entry for the target host in `~/.netrc` with the following form:

```
machine <address>
login <username>
password <password>
```

where you replace `<address>`, `<login>` and `<password>`  with the host address, username and password respectively. You should also make sure that `~/.netrc` has proper permissions (i.e. is only readable and writable by the owner). This approach has the advantage that the credentials are stored in a single place which can be accessed from multiple scripts. It is also easier to make sure `~/.netrc` has proper permissions than to manage permissions for *all* scripts which might need to use the credentials.

Then you can proceed to either to pass commands to `ftp` via a *[here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)* or use [`lftp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp) with the `-c` option to pass the commands as command line arguments. Note that if you go for the former, you should *not* specify the `-n` option to `ftp` as this will disable auto-login using the credentials stored in `~/.netrc`.